# Make each tab section unique instead of triggering other elements

Tags: javascript

I am having a select box that works as tabs, it works fine whenever there is one section. However I want to make it work for multiple of sections, I want it basically to be unique and work at its own. I can't add custom class for a different element in html because it's being added dynamically through html system and all have same classes. Is there way to work around this using javascript?

```js
const selectList = document.querySelectorAll("select");

for (let i = 0; i < selectList.length; i++) {
  selectList[i].addEventListener("change", toggle);
}

function toggle(e) {
  e.target.closest(".section").querySelectorAll(".ul-data").forEach((el) => {
    el.hidden = el.dataset["name"] !== e.target.value;
  });
}
```

```html
<select class="dropdown">
   <option value="test">Test</option>
   <option value="test1">Test1</option>
</select>
<div class="section section-1">
   <ul class="ul-data" data-name="test">
      <li>Item</li>
   </ul>
</div>
<select class="dropdown">
   <option value="test">Test</option>
   <option value="test1">Test1</option>
</select>
<div class="section section-2">
   <ul class="ul-data" data-name="test">
      <li>Item</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see in the snippet, when you change the first section value the other section changes too which I do not want to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `nextElementSibling` to find the element that comes directly after `e.target` (the select box). However i recommend to edit the html structure so there is a wrapper around the `select` and the `ul`elements to prevent your code form breaking when the html changes so that there will be an element in between.

You could write your own function similar to closest but for siblings too.

```js
const selectList = document.querySelectorAll("select");

for (let i = 0; i < selectList.length; i++) {
  selectList[i].addEventListener("change", toggle);
}

function toggle(e) {
  e.target.nextElementSibling.querySelectorAll(".ul-data").forEach((el) => {
    el.hidden = el.dataset["name"] !== e.target.value;
  });
}
```

```html
<select class="dropdown">
  <option value="test">Test</option>
  <option value="test1">Test1</option>
</select>
<div class="section section-1">
  <ul class="ul-data" data-name="test">
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<select class="dropdown">
  <option value="test">Test</option>
  <option value="test1">Test1</option>
</select>
<div class="section section-2">
  <ul class="ul-data" data-name="test">
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry my bad, there should be only one element in ul. Is there way to make this work while wrapping the ul with `<div class="section-2"><ul...`? I am trying to modify  the example and take .closest from ul parent but getting `null` when I log it.

Comment: Can you please check my edited post?

Comment: @squnk I would advice to create a wrapper around each select/ul pair. However if you really want to keep the structure you could use [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling). I'll update my answer.

Comment: I am aware it would be better to add a wrapper and If I would do it, but I have to keep this structure no matter what. Would be nice if you could update with it.

Comment: @squnk Just made an update.

Answer (score 1):

You should target the parents  which class starts with `^=` `"section-"`.
Than, when selecting your elements make sure they're queried not from `document` but from their parent section-*N* Element

```js
const EL = (sel, el) => (el || document).querySelector(sel);
const ELS = (sel, el) => (el || document).querySelectorAll(sel);

const ELS_section = ELS('[class^="section-"], [class*=" section-"]');
// PS: use rather a common ".section" in HTML 

ELS_section.forEach(EL_section => {

  const ELS_select = EL(".dropdown", EL_section); // descendant of EL_section
  const ELS_ul = ELS(".ul-data", EL_section);     // descendants of EL_section

  ELS_select.addEventListener("change", () => {
    const name = ELS_select.value;
    ELS_ul.forEach(EL_ul => {
      EL_ul.hidden = name && EL_ul.dataset.name !== name;
    });
  });
  
});
```

```html
<div class="section-1">

  <select class="dropdown">
    <option value="">-- All --</option>
    <option value="test">Test</option>
    <option value="test1">Test1</option>
  </select>

  <ul class="ul-data" data-name="test">
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="ul-data" data-name="test1">
    <li>Test1</li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div class="section-2">

  <select class="dropdown">
    <option value="">-- All --</option>
    <option value="test">Test</option>
    <option value="test1">Test1</option>
  </select>

  <ul class="ul-data" data-name="test">
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="ul-data" data-name="test1">
    <li>Test1</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try This:

```js
const selectList = document.querySelectorAll("select");

for (let i = 0; i < selectList.length; i++) {
  selectList[i].addEventListener("change", toggle);
}

function toggle(e) {
  let parent = e.target.closest("[class^='section-']");
  if(!parent) return;
  let ulList = parent.querySelectorAll(".ul-data");

  for (let i = 0; i < ulList.length; i++) {
    ulList[i].hidden = ulList[i].dataset["name"] !== e.target.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section-1">

  <select class="dropdown">
    <option value="test">Test</option>
    <option value="test1">Test1</option>

  </select>

  <ul class="ul-data" data-name="test">
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="ul-data" data-name="test1">
    <li>Item2</li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div class="section-2">

  <select class="dropdown">
    <option value="test">Test</option>
    <option value="test1">Test1</option>

  </select>

  <ul class="ul-data" data-name="test">
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="ul-data" data-name="test1">
    <li>Item2</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: `parentElement` will fail as soon you change slightly the HTML. JS should not break for such minor changes. instead use `.closest()`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks for help, updated